# Direct digital audio connection from one Windows-PC to another via USB

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, digital-audio

I have two Windows PCs and one audio amp connected to the second PC. I'm trying to hear audio from both, ie, share the amp between the two PCs.

I tried a regular mixer but I get hum and whine loud enough to be annoying.

I tried using a male-male 3.5mm stereo cable to connect line-out on the first PC to line-in on the second, then passing the audio straight through using "Listen to this device" in the microphone properties on the second PC. But just like with the mixer, I get hum and whine in the signal.

So I want to do it digitally. I figure I can probably buy a peripheral that will connect optical out from the first PC to USB-in on the second. But perhaps I can do it direct using USB? Does anyone know how?

Comment: Is USB mandatory? (compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)). If yes: [this oldish answer](https://superuser.com/a/143863/432690) for a start (I don't know if USB 3 changes anything). If no, then (1) please [edit] and at least change the title. (2) Are the PCs in the same LAN? What is the latency (ping)? Do not answer in comments, [edit] the question.

Comment: I'm sure it would be a whole lot simpler to figure out why your first idea, through a mixer, didn't work as expected.