# How do I make my windows 10 PC act as a usb flash drive?

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, storage

I want to install Ubuntu from a bootable usb but currently don't have access to a USB flash drive for storage, What I do have though is a two-way USB (type A) cable and I'm thinking I could plug one end into my PC and have it disguise itself as a USB storage device from it's own end. Is there any software that would let me do this?

Google is no help for my particular question because it thinks that i want to create bootables from a physical USB flash drive that I have no access to.

Comment: I do not really understand. You can make any USB flash key bootable with Rufus for example

Comment: I don't have a USB flash storage device of any kind, that's why I'm looking for any possibilities of having my PC pretend to be one.

Comment: Spend 1-3 USD and buy a stick.  What a total waste of time.  You are never going to succeed at this endeavor.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas What a total waste of a comment, you are never going to realize I don't event assume It's practically possible. Unlike you I seek to challenge and disprove my own intuition instead of suffering from Dunning-Kruger like you.

Comment: Your highly intelligent words hurt me to my core.  *SOME* of us have been around long enough to know when something is a waste of time.  Can people NOT suffering from the dunning-kruger make pigs fly?  Do whatever you like.  Say whatever makes you feel better.  Good luck to you on this (and anger management).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas You assumed something, and were wrong. and now you assumed a second thing, and were wrong again! Your arrogance and overconfidence already tells me everything, but keep doing you I guess. 

Answer (score 4):

What you are actually asking has been greatly answered over here:

[Emulate a USB port as a USB flash drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/143782/emulate-a-usb-port-as-a-usb-flash-drive?rq=1)

You can try to boot ubuntu from a DVD, an usb stick or using PXE and network boot.

But, to be honest with you the easier way would be just to get a usb stick, or virtualize.

Cheers!

Comment: Given that the topic was asked and answered 11 years ago, it's possible things might've changed since then. Specifically the USB protocol which is now on 3.0 if not even more recent, my motherboard is also new and should support any modern USB features if there exists any.

Comment: I didn't read this post enough before my original comment.  You sir were not wrong in the one fact that this is a total waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you cannot have a PC that can do this function. To do so a PC must have a dual-role USB port (formerly known as "OTG port", now it is DRD - Dual-Role-Data). To have the dual-role port, your PC must have the Host Controller Interface (to be a normal USB host), and also have a Device Controller built in, with a multiplexor between the two functions. Most likely you will find this dual-role functionality in small gadgets like smartphones and tablets, over Type-C USB port in recent days, but most laptops don't have the device functionality built-in (except for a very specific device as "debug port"), and no desktops have the DRD AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

you should consider [PXE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) Boot/Install instead.
It uses an Ethernet connection instead of a USB drive

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward to do with Linux (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120368/make-a-computer-act-as-a-virtual-usb-device-for-other-equipments) using Gadget. Has no one solved this problem with Windows?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).